# how to create ETL to dynamically get the port name

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter

i have a table

```
table:

col1,col2

1,2

3,4
```

i want to create ETL to extract only port/column name in another table example my target table should contain one column with 2 rows contain column names

```
target:

target_column

col1

col2
```

so how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Query the metadata. Depending on the type of your DB this may differ. For MySQL that would be:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name' 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';
```

Here, try [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d3U2UzeAYNhNFTYWkpi5yS/0).